# Scrapy en Python extraccion con xpaths

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Estoy scrapeando texto de una pagina web con un spider en Python donde la salida es un .csv. Logré extraer lo que quiero para 1 solo campo, pero necesito agregar otro campo más al lado, el cual tenga su respectiva información.

De momento el spider genera los 2 campos pero solamente me los llena con la información de uno de los dos, en vez de cada uno con su información correspondiente.

Así se me genera ahora (la misma información en los dos campos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaría que se me genere así (cada campo con su información extraída respectiva):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación dejo mi código:

spider.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from verbos.items import MercadoItem

class MercadoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'verbos'
allowed_domain = ['www.pt.bab.la']
print("Ingrese un verbo:")
variable = input()
start_urls = ['https://pt.bab.la/verbo/portugues/' + variable]


def parse(self, response):

    response.selector.remove_namespaces()

    for xpath in ('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',  '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', ' //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'):
       words=response.xpath(xpath).getall()
    for xpath in ('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'):
       words=response.xpath(xpath).getall()
       for word in words:
        yield {'eu': word, 'voce': word}
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy


class MercadoItem(scrapy.Item):
eu = scrapy.Field()
voce = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'verbos'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['verbos.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'verbos.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'verbos.pipelines.MercadoPipeline': 200}

FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = 'verbos_items.csv'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='cp1252'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahora mismo ambos ciclos comparten la misma variable generada en cada iteración (`xpath`), como ademaś el ciclo que crea el generador es el segundo, el primer ciclo no sirve de nada y sus datos se pierden. Cada item del generdor debe ser una fila del csv, por lo que solo debes tener un ciclo que en cada iteración analize las parejas de XPATHS de ambas tuplas (campos).

Puedes usar simplemente `zip`. Una forma general que es relativamente fácil de escalar si quieres agregar campos en el futuro podría ser:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from verbos.items import MercadoItem



class MercadoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'verbos'
    allowed_domain = ['www.pt.bab.la']
    print("Ingrese un verbo:")
    variable = input()
    start_urls = ['https://pt.bab.la/verbo/portugues/' + variable]

    EU_XPATHS = (
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', 
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        ' //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'
        )
    VOCE_XPATHS= (
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
        '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'
        )
    CAMPOS = ("eu", "voce")


    def parse(self, response):
        response.selector.remove_namespaces()        
        for xpaths in zip(self.EU_XPATHS, self.VOCE_XPATHS):
            data = [response.xpath(xpath).getall() for xpath in xpaths]
            yield {campo: valor for campo, valor in zip(self.CAMPOS, data)}
```

Comment: me funcionó a la perfección! muchisimas gracias!!